# PostgreSql: function returns records, one of filed may be int or bool

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to create a function which returns set of records but one of fields can be int or bool depending on condiotion?

Something like this:

```
if cond then
   return query select x,y, int
else
  return query select x,y, bool
end if;
```

I am trying to simulate a behavior of SQL Server sqlvariant type

Comment: No, each column must have a well defined type. If you want, you can cast the bool into an int, which will convert it to a 0 or 1.

Comment: I need to have more types, i.e. int, bool, text, timestamp etc..

Comment: Maybe you could convert them to text then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A record can contain columns of any type. So if you declare a function to return a (`setof`) records it can return anything:

```
create or replace function f(_param int)
returns setof record as $$
begin
    if _param = 1 then
        return query select 1, true;
    else
        return query select 1, 'text';
    end if;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

The catch is that it is necessary to declare the returned columns' types at each usage:

```
select * 
from f(1) s (a int, b boolean);
 a | b 
---+---
 1 | t
```